# Does every job call in Spring Batch open a new database connection pool?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I'm querying rows from a database using JDBC template and for each rows, I'm programmatically running a job which executes a chunk-based step. I'm worried that each job call will create a new set of connection pool. Does it create a new set of connection pool or just connect to the current pool?

Main Method (Runs the job for each stores):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
    JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {

SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainApp.class);
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
Job job = ctx.getBean("customerJob", Job.class);

storeRepository = ctx.getBean(StoreRepository.class);
customerRepository = ctx.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

List<Store> stores = storeRepository.findAll(); 


for (Store store: stores) {
    int customerCount = customerRepository.countCustomer(store.getStoreID(), reportDate);
    System.out.println("Count: "+ customerCount);
    if (customerCount != 0) {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("reportDate", reportDate)
        .addString("ID", store.getStoreID())
        .toJobParameters();
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    BatchStatus batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
    System.out.println("Batch Status " + batchStatus);
    }
    

}
}
```

Batch Job Configuration:

```
@Bean
public Step generateReport() throws Exception {
return this.stepBuilderFactory
    .get("generateReport")
    .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
    .reader(itemReader(null, null))
    .writer(itemWriter())
    .build();
}

@Bean
public Job customerReportJob() throws Exception {
return this.jobBuilderFactory
    .get("customerReportJob")
    .start(generateReport())
    .build();
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {

private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
    public CustomerRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

@Override
public List<Customer> findByIDAndReportDate(String ID, String reportDate) {
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * " +  
    "FROM CUSTOMER_REPORT " +
    "WHERE ID = " +  ID + "  " +
    "AND TO_CHAR(REPORT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = '" + reportDate + "'";

return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, 
    (rs, rowNum) -> 
    new Customer(mapper(rs)));
}
}
```

application.properties:

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=##
spring.datasource.username=##
spring.datasource.password=##
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=##

# Hikari
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=debug

# Spring Batch
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

Comment: No Lester, it doesn't. If you have one Datasource bean with default scope (Singleton), then it doesn't create new connection pool per chunk.

Comment: Hi @Faraz, how about per job call? Are the connections closed automatically after each job? Will there be a chance to have a connection leak?

Comment: It depends on bean scopes. Is the connection pool shared between jobs? Please share your code to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: Unless you're doing weird things, I would expect that you have a single data source, so it won't repeatedly create a new connection pool. However, without seeing the actual code and config, we can't be sure about that.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, I added the code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, I added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your configuration, your jobs will use the same datasource/connection pool. You should be able to confirm that by looking at the logs.